# How to print arguments of all types of Exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to print the arguments of all types of exception caught in the below code snippet?

I want to catch all the exceptions and send the message as string to another function(say, "note_this_error"). By message, I mean whatever gets printed on the screen had there not been any exception handling code.

```
try: 
    :: 
except Exception as e: 
    print e.args 
    note_this_error (exception_message_as_string)
```

I saw the following on [Official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html):

> When an exception occurs, it may have an associated value, also known
>   as the exception’s argument. The presence and type of the argument
>   depend on the exception type.

I use Python 2.7

Comment: you mean `e.message` or the type of error also?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I wanted something like traceback.format_exc() 
I referred to the linked question and found that. Thanks anyways for your comment

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed that question linked by you is what I wanted but was not able to find through google. Thanks for linking that question. If you want, we can close this (my) question.